# Hide specific Div based on text inside another div using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to do logic using javascript, so that if div where class is b-format if innerhtml value is Audio it will hide cart-button div, else it will hide the more-button div. For some reason its not working.

```
var itemButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.slider-wrapper');

for(var i=0; i<itemButtons.length; i++){

   var b_format_element = itemButtons[i].getElementsByClassName("b-format")[0];
   var cart_element = itemButtons[i].getElementsByClassName("cart-button")[0];
   var more_element = itemButtons[i].getElementsByClassName("more-button")[0];
   
   if(b_format_element.innerHTML == "Audio"){
     cart_element.style.display = "none";
   } else {
     more_element.style.display = "none";
   }
}
```

this is html code

```
<div class="slider-wrapper">
       ${#Recommend} // this repeat record
       <a class="product" href="#">
           <div>
               <p class="b-format">Audio</p>
           </div>
             
               <div class="product-items cart-button">
                 <span>Read more</span>
               </div>
                                                                               
               <div class="product actions product-items more-button">
                 <span>Read more</span>
               </div>
               
       </a>
       ${/Recommend}
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not good idea to use the same ID tags over and over in a loop. Instead, use a class name. Also, using `querySelector` will get you the first matching element. It also looks like you want to cycle through the inner DIVs of the slider-container, rather than cycling through multiple slider containers. I added an inner container `.record`.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.slider-wrapper .record').forEach(c => {
  let isAudio = c.querySelector('.b-format')?.innerText.trim() === 'Audio';
  c.querySelector('.cart-button').style.display = isAudio ? 'none' : 'block';
  c.querySelector('.more-button').style.display = !isAudio ? 'none' : 'block';
})
```

```css
.cart-button {
  color: #f00;
}

.more-button {
  color: #999;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider-wrapper">
  <div class='record'>
    <div>
      <p class="b-format">Audio</p>
    </div>
    <!-- buttom -->
    <div class="cart-button">
      <span>Les mer</span>
    </div>
    <div class="more-button">
      <span>Les mer</span>
    </div>
    <!-- button end -->
  </div>
  <div class='record'>
    <div>
      <p class="b-format">Not Audio</p>
    </div>
    <!-- buttom -->
    <div class="cart-button">
      <span>Les mer</span>
    </div>
    <div class="more-button">
      <span>Les mer</span>
    </div>
    <!-- button end -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is also only applying to first item not the rest of items for some reason!

Comment: I have updated code a bit and also replaced id with class, now if i run my code it is also applying to first item of the list, i have updated html as well please check suggest if you see any thing missing.

Comment: Take a look at my updated answer. I think I see where you're getting stuck